# Get previous branch name

Tags: git, git-checkout

I really like `git checkout -` to move to my previous branch.

But sometimes I only need to know what my previous branch name is. How could I ask Git that?

For example, if `git checkout -` moves to branch "prev", I want the command to get just "prev".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`git checkout -` is shorthand for `git checkout @{-1}` (see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-ltbranchgt)):

> You can use the `@{-N}` syntax to refer to the N-th last branch/commit
>   checked out using "git checkout" operation. You may also specify `-`
>   which is synonymous to `@{-1}`.

You can pass this same reference to [`rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) to get the commit or branch in question:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git checkout not-master
Switched to branch 'not-master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/not-master'.
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-1}
refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Great! FYI I made an alias as follows: `git config --global alias.prev 'rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{-1}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref=loose @{-1}
```

The advantage over the previous answer is that it returns the plain name of the branch, without /refs/heads/master