# git checkout to other branch by index

Tags: git

I'd like to checkout to other branches by providing an index instead of the full branch name. I often have many branches open with long names, e.g.

```
issue-555-lorem-ipsum-dolor
issue-555-sit-amet-bar
issue-123-foo-bar
master
```

Currently, I'm just doing (with tab autocomplete):

```
git checkout issue-555-lorem-ipsum-dolor
```

Instead, I'd like to do something like (pseudo code):

```
git checkout [1]
```

Does git have anything similar right now? I had a look at the docs but didn't find anything similar. It would speed up my workflow a little bit.

Comment: I don't think git has an idea of the "index" of the branches, they have *names* and are shown in alphabetical order of those names. However you can move between branches by index based on *recent usage*, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61128146/3001761

Comment: It sounds like you want to essentially give your branches aliases, which aren't supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365946/git-branch-alias#:~:text=Git%20does%20not%20support%20aliases%20for%20branches.&text=Specifically%2C%20take%20a%20look%20at,not%20as%20histories%20of%20folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias for that. In example:

```
  # enumerate branches
  branchn = ! git branch | nl
  # checkout based on index
  checkoutn = "!f(){ git checkout $(git branch | sed \"$1q;d\"); }; f"
```

`branchn` enumerates branches, while `checkoutn` checkouts based on the index in enumerated list.

Example usage:

```
git checkoutn 2
```